# Nodejs generating a azure sas url using generateBlobSASQueryParameters in @azure/storage-blob module

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, azure-storage

Hi I have a azure storage account where i will upload and create a sas url to download the image. below is the code that i used ,

```
const {
  BlobServiceClient,
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
  BlobSASPermissions,
  generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");


const clientCred = new ClientSecretCredential(process.env.STORAGE_TENANT,process.env.STORAGE_APPID,process.env.STORAGE_PASSWORD)

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  clientCred
  
  );

  var blobName = "blobName";
    var containeName = process.env.PROFILE_UPLOAD_CONTAINER_NAME;
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containeName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    const response = await blockBlobClient.uploadData(image.data, {
      blobHTTPHeaders: {
        blobContentType: image.mimetype,
      },
    });
    if (response.etag) {
      const cerds = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
        process.env.STORAGE_APPID,** ( earlier i used account name and key it worked perfectly fine)**
        process.env.STORAGE_PASSWORD
      );
      const date = new Date();
      const expires = new Date(
        Date.UTC(
          date.getFullYear() + 2,
          date.getMonth(),
          date.getDate(),
          23,
          59,
          59
        )
      );
  
      const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
        {
          containerName: containeName,
          blobName: blobName,
          expiresOn: expires,
          permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"),
        },
        **cerds** (i need to create cerds using tenantid,appid and password)
      ).toString();
      const sasUrl = blockBlobClient.url + "?" + sasToken;
      console.log("sasUrl", sasUrl);
```

I will not have account key. How to access the sasurl by using only tenantid,appid and password. Kindly guide

I am able to upload using tenantid,appid and password , but when i try to create a downloadable sasurl i am unable to  do so, using the above tenantid,appid and password

Answer (score 1):

> I will not have an account key. How to access the sasurl by using only tenantid, app id and password. Kindly guide

You can use the user delegation key method without using the account key to create sas url with tenantid, app id and password.

You can use the below code to create the SAS-URL with tenantid, app id and password.

**Code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient, generateBlobSASQueryParameters, BlobSASPermissions,SASProtocol, BlobClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

async  function  CreateblobSas(){

   const accountName = 'venky890';
   const containerName = 'test';
   const blobName = 'sampleimage.jpg';
   const clientId = 'Your-client-id';
   const tenantId = 'Your-tenant-id';
   const clientSecret = 'Your-password';
   const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

   const  TEN_MINUTES = 10 * 60 * 1000;
   const  NOW = new  Date();
   const  TEN_MINUTES_BEFORE_NOW = new  Date(NOW.valueOf() - TEN_MINUTES);
   const  TEN_MINUTES_AFTER_NOW = new  Date(NOW.valueOf() + TEN_MINUTES);
   const  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClient(
 `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  credential)
   const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
   
// Get a reference to your blob
   const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
   
// When using a user delegation key, container must already exist
   const  userDelegationKey = await  blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(
     TEN_MINUTES_BEFORE_NOW,
     TEN_MINUTES_AFTER_NOW
    );
// Best practice: SAS options are time-limited
   const  sasOptions = {
      containerName,
      blobName,
      permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"),
      protocol:  SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp,
      startsOn:  TEN_MINUTES_BEFORE_NOW,
      expiresOn:  TEN_MINUTES_AFTER_NOW
    };
    const  sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
     sasOptions,
     userDelegationKey,
     accountName
     ).toString();
     console.log(`${blobClient.url}?${sasToken}`)
}
CreateblobSas()
```

**Output:**

```
https://venky890.blob.core.windows.net/test/sampleimage.jpg?<SAStoken>
```

[image]